# Revert action enabled but not doing action

Tags: jmeter

About JMeter File →  Revert action,

It's remain enabled even after saving (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) while changing test and then when choosing Revert not doing any action.

It seems that it need to be disabled when saving because it doesn't revert after save.

Is it a bug or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be considered as a bug.

Indeed it should be disabled between last save and until first modification of test plan.
Feel free to submit a patch or PR.